# CSS nav-link not changing on hover

Tags: html, css

Why does my hover CSS not affect the links in my website?

```css
.nav-link {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: #A46FA6 1px solid;
  width: auto;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-link :hover {
  background-color: #6D256F;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <header id="navbar-header"> Overview </header>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#Topic_1">Topic 1</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#Topic_2">Topic 2</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#Topic_3">Topic 3</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#Topic_4">Topic 4</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#Topic_5">Topic 5</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Because you have a space in it. In CSS, a space between selectors is used to represent the [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator).

Comment: Because - with the space - you're styling the descendent elements of the `.nav-link` elements when the descendant is hovered; learn about the [descendant combinator (` `)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)).

Comment: Ahh i see that makes sense thank you both

Comment: Change `.nav-link :hover ` to `.nav-link:hover ` ... as commented, no space between the _class_ and _:hover_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The :hover must not be spaced from the element you are describing.

```css
.nav-link {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: #A46FA6 1px solid;
  width: auto;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  background-color: #6D256F;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <header id="navbar-header"> Overview </header>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#Topic_1">Topic 1</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#Topic_2">Topic 2</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#Topic_3">Topic 3</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#Topic_4">Topic 4</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#Topic_5">Topic 5</a>
</nav>
```